# Sh script not running using cron while running using terminal manually

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a script .sh that works when executed manually but not working through cron :

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo find . -name "*.log" -delete
```

There are other .sh which runs perfectly with cron.

I don't know why this one doesn't work.

I compared the env output from the terminal and from cron and both are similar beside the user which has higher privilege in cron using :

```
echo env > output.txt
```

The only difference between this script and others which work is the location of the file.

If anyone had a similar problem or know how to get more precise logs.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you can add `sudo pwd` to see what it gives.

Comment: Your script is probably not being run with the current working directory you think it is.

Comment: @Castiell : It's very brave to run a file-deleting  `sudo` command from _cron_ without testing it (i.e. having it displaying the files it would actually delete). After all, `.` most likely denotes a different directory within the cron context than inside your terminal.

Comment: @user1934428 This machine is already a test machine where I can do anything I want + i ask for deleting log files which is absolutely safe in my case but thank you for pointing it .
Your answer is correct the "." is not pointing where i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Shawn and @user1834428 in the comment the "." in my script was not pointing where I wanted.